# Angle consistency between vectors in N dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

I am trying to understand how rotations work in higher dimensions. Let us assume we have a set of points $p_i\in P$ in $N$ dimensions, related to another set of points $q_i \in Q$ by a rotation $R$. Because each pair $(p_i,q_i)$ spans a plane, it is possible to find the angle between the two vectors simply with the dot product.

Indeed, if I do calculate the dot product between all normalised pairs of points with $N=2$, I get the same result for all pairs. However, this does not happen whenever I increase the number of dimensions. Why is that? I would have expected a uniform result as well, and I am having a bit of trouble picturing why this is.

Comment: Think of a 3D rotation that rotates in the $xy$ plane but leaves the $z$ direction the same. Any point along the $z$-axis stays the same, so the angle is zero, but points in the $xy$ plane will be rotated appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In three dimensions the axis of rotation may not be perpendicular to the vectors.  Let us think about rotating around the $z$ axis by $\frac \pi2$.  If $p_1=(1,0,0)$ it rotates to $q_1=(0,1,0)$ and the dot product is zero because they are perpendicular.  But if $p_2=(1,0,1)$ it will rotate to $q_2=(0,1,1)$ and the dot product is $1$

Comment: I see, thank you. So I guess there is no 'invariant' in higher dimensions without knowing the underlying rotation?

Comment: @maruko:  In three dimensions you can decompose the vectors into a part parallel to the axis and a part perpendicular to the axis.  The parallel part doesn't change and the perpendicular part gets rotated just like 2D, so the dot products of the perpendicular part will be uniform.  I don't have good intuition about higher dimensions